# Why does byte order marker appear out of nowhere when I concatenate files?

Tags: c#, .net, byte-order-mark

I have a folder with XML files and I need to merge them into one file. When I try this:

```
var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml");
String result = Path.Combine( path, "merged.xml" );
using( var stream = new FileStream( result, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write ) ) {
    foreach( var file in allFiles ) {
        var fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes( file );
        stream.Write( fileContents , 0, fileContents.Length );
    }
    stream.Close();
}
```

I see that `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF` (the byte order marker) sequence appears in the result file between the content of any two files but not at the start of the file and not at the end of the file.

If I use `StreamWriter` instead:

```
var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml");
String result = Path.Combine( path, "merged.xml" );
using( var stream = new FileStream( result, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write ) ) {
    using( var writer = new StreamWriter( stream ) ) {
        foreach( var file in allFiles ) {
           var fileText = File.ReadAllText( file );
           writer.Write( fileText );
        }
    }
    stream.Close();
}
```

then the sequence does not appear.

How does it happen that I'm reading and writing the files as binary and some byte sequence gets injected?

Comment: How are you verifying the BOM is not in your input file? I'll bet that it is and that whatever you're using to check is stripping it out...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original files have BOMs in them.
`File.ReadAllBytes()` faithfully returns those bytes, just like any other byte.

`File.ReadAllText()` parses the bytes as UTF8, stripping the BOMs.

Comment: The deal is the marker does not appear at the start of the result and at the end of the result - only inside the result.

Comment: @sharptooth: That would happen if only the middle files have them.  Open the original files in a hex editor.

Comment: Ouch. Indeed the first file has no marker and all other files do have it.